# Where is Electron's app.getAppPath() pointing to?

Tags: electron, package.json

I am using browserify to merge all the .js files of my app into a `dist/main.js`. My `package.json` looks like:

```
"main": "./dist/main.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron ./dist/main.js",
},
"bin": {
  "electron": "./node_modules/.bin/electron"
}
```

and I can correctly run my application with `npm run start`.
However if in `main.js` I use `app.getAppPath()` I get:

`/home/myuser/projects/electronProject/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar`

I would expect this to be

`/home/myuser/projects/electronProject/dist/main.js`

Did I misunderstood the usage of this method? How can I get the path of the Electron program entrypoint? What is the role of `default_app.asar`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using `__dirname` (node.js) or `process.resourcesPath` (electron)?

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/process.md
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Actually the question comes from the fact [electron-reload](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload) is using it, and in fact it does not seem to work for me. I will forward your question as github issue to the author.

Comment: Just a comment that .. Using __dirname is a more resilient solution than getAppPath(). Based on your package.json you might get unexpected results otherwise

Answer (score 2):

It returns the current application directory:

> `app.getAppPath()`
>   Returns String - The current application directory.

From the [docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetapppath).

An asar file is a simple archive format that just appends the files to each other. I'm not sure exactly how you're building the application but tools like `electron-packager` and `electron-builder` output the files into a `resources/app.asar` archive and run the files from there. That means that your current application directory is going to be `something/resources/app.asar`. From there your main file is located at `something/resources/app.asar/main.js`.

Comment: The fact is that I am not using neither `electron-packager` not `electron-builder`. Electron is launched with files that are not in a `.asar` package and that's why I do not understand why it is pointing there. The docs say *current application directory*, which is quite ambiguous in my opinion.

Comment: Same problem, I'm using VSCode. In the launch.json file, `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` still not working. Do you solve it now?

Answer (score 2):

For whom may ran into the same problem...
It's maybe a problem with your electron configuration field `main` in `package.json`

> The script specified by the main field is the startup script of your
>   app, which will run the main process.

The example code from [offical websites](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#electron-development-in-a-nutshell):

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
}
```

app.getAppPath() output:

> YOUR_PATH_TO/electron-quick-start

If you change the code snippet to

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron YOUR_PATH_TO/main.js"
  }
}
```

Then app.getAppPath() output:

> YOUR_PATH_TO/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar

So the consolution is : If you want to change the **startup script**, change it in the **main** field, not just change it in **scritps** field...

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. __dirname is the way to go